Nginx rewrite inside location
Does make sense using of nginx rewrite statement with break flag inside location?
location {
rewrite path1 path2 break;
}

Seems like in this case it does'nt matter wich path2 is being used. Or maybe someone can provide some real world example of using path2 in this case?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You would use break to stay inside that location rather than looking for another. If you have a different value for root, or have set some custom headers, or have a proxy_pass or fastcgi_pass configuration inside that location.
